# Inject secret value to configmap during deployment without using environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I have a configmap like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: develop
  name: test-config
data:
  app.conf: |
    connection conn1
    address 127.0.0.1:8080
    user cluster1
    password: <HERE COPY PASS FROM SECRET>
```

app.conf section is mounted as a configuration file inside the container using

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: container-name
          ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-config-vol
              mountPath: /etc/app/app.conf
              subPath: app.conf
      volumes:
        - name: test-config-vol
          configMap:
            name: test-config
```

the app reading that file is NOT able to read environment variables, and I cannot change that behavior, it is a third party app.

I wonder how can I inject password from a secret into password field during pod deployment

Comment: Why to not get the password from the secret? why to pass it to a configmap, which is not intended to keep passwords?

Answer (score 5):

You can't, what you can do is mounting a [Kuberentes secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret) with the password - see the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#secret). So you'll end up having 2 files - one from the config map and one from the secret.

If your app does not support multiple config files, you'll have to store the entire config file on the secret instead of the config map.

Also, please note that Kubernetes secrets cannot be stored on source control, as the secret data is encoded using base64 (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#security-properties) for more details). There are multiple solutions for this problem, check out my [post](https://itnext.io/can-kubernetes-keep-a-secret-it-all-depends-what-tool-youre-using-498e5dee9c25)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an init container to:

1. Mount to configMap
2. Mount an emptyDir volume
3. Use envsubst to do the substitution and write the output to the emptyDir volume.
4. Mount the emptyDir volume in your app container

Here is an example that works:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  config.yaml: |
    connection conn1
    address 127.0.0.1:8080
    user cluster1
    password: $PASSWORD
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  PASSWORD: dmFsdWUtMg0KDQo=
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: substitute-config
          image: alpine
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: my-secret
          command:
            - "sh"
            - "-c"
            - apk add gettext && envsubst < /sourceconf/config.yaml > /finalconfig/config.yaml
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configmap
              mountPath: /sourceconf
            - name: config
              mountPath: /finalconfig
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: alpine
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["sh", "-c", "cat /finalconfig/config.yaml && sleep 300"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /finalconfig
      volumes:
        - name: configmap
          configMap:
            name: my-config
        - name: config
          emptyDir: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Result:

```
-> # k logs my-deployment-77f4476c94-nxgwj
Defaulted container "my-app" out of: my-app, substitute-config (init)
connection conn1
address 127.0.0.1:8080
user cluster1
password: value-2
```